# creo que hay un error en el condicional del metodo *darPesoEnKilogramos

Tags: java

```
package taller_practico;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author salas
 */
public class Punto5 {


    // ---------------------------
    //--------------atributos
    private double pesoEnToneladas;
    private double pesoEnKilogramos;
    //------------------------------
    //---------------getters and setters 

    public double getPesoEnToneladas() {
        return pesoEnToneladas;
    }

    public void getPesoEnToneladas(double pesoEnToneladas) {
        this.pesoEnToneladas = pesoEnToneladas;
    }

    public double getPesoEnKilogramos() {
        return pesoEnKilogramos;
    }

    public void setPesoEnKilogramos(double pesoEnKilogramos) {
        this.pesoEnKilogramos = pesoEnKilogramos;
    }

//_-------------------------------
    // constructor vacio
    public Punto5() {
   }
    //--------------------------------
    //----------convertir peso a kilogramos

    public double darPesoEnKilogramos(double pesoEntoneladas){
         double pesoEnKilogramos = 0.0;

        if(pesoEnToneladas>=4 && pesoEnToneladas<=7.5){
            pesoEnKilogramos = pesoEnToneladas*1000;

        }/*else{

             salida ="el peso a ingresar no puede ser menor a 4 toneladas ni mayor a 7.5 toneladas";
        }*/
        return pesoEnKilogramos;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Punto5 punto5 = new Punto5();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ingrese el peso del elefante en toneladas");
        double pesoEnToneladas = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(punto5.darPesoEnKilogramos(pesoEnToneladas));


    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes Ciro, te recomiendo leas [**_¿Como Preguntar?_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para darle una formulación mas correcta a tu pregunta, ademas has el [**_Recorrido_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor el sitio y ganar tu primer medalla!

Comment: En Java los nombres de variable son *case sensitive*. Por tanto esto: `pesoEntoneladas` y esto `pesoEnToneladas` no es lo mismo, la `t` y la `T` hacen una diferencia que pesa toneladas capaces de romper un programa. Debes ser cuidadoso cuando escribes tus variables. [Puedes leerlo aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), al final, en el apartado titulado **Naming**.